# Issue with AWS MSK with TLS, with Spring-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-fargate, aws-msk, amazon-msk

Anyone used AWS MSK with TLS, with Spring-kafka, below are the details of our application, with the config below, the application is not working

1. we have deployed our consumers/producers on Fargate
2. kafka-client version is 2.1.1
3. below are the configuration values used as part of consumer and producer

   ```
    spring.kafka.ssl.protocol=ssl
    spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/home/ec2-user/truststore.jks
    spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=ssl
    spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers:"xxxx:9094,xxxx:9094,xxxx:9094"
   ```

When we deploy the application, Fargate instances are continuously restarting, throwing out-of-memory Exception, but our task definition is with 4cpu and 12 GB RAM, usually application runs well with 2cpu and 4 GB RAM. Also application was working well earlier with self-hosted Kafka.

Comment: Could you share some of these logs to get a picture of what is causing the issue?